# Most suitable data structure for unique PDF uploading

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I've been given an assignment at university that consists of storing PDF documents efficiently in a PDF store and only once (no content duplication by uploading the same file multiple times).

The method being the following `store(String title, File pdfFile)`

**Example 1:**

```
"Fast Cars", fastcars.pdf
"Even Faster Cars", fastcars.pdf
"Not So Fast Cars", cars.pdf
"Slow Cars", slowcars.pdf
```

**Expected Result:** It should have a size of 3 containing the following `fastcars.pdf, cars.pdf and slowcars.pdf`

**Example 2:**

```
"Fast Cars", fastcars.pdf
"Even Faster Cars", fastcars.pdf
"Fast Cars", sportscars.pdf
"Even Faster Cars", sportscars.pdf
```

It should have size 1 and only containing `sportscars.pdf`

My idea is to content hash the pdf and possibly use a HashMap mapping the content digest hash with a random integer and later mapping that to the PDF title?

The tricky part is trying to satisfy Example 2.

What data structure would you recommend for this problem for efficiency and what approach would you take?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like the algorithm only depends on the title and the filename. If this is the case, you do not need to hash anything. For the second example, it looks like it is just a matter of making sure that your order of operations is correct and that you make the right choice when deciding what to keep. But I will not do your homework for you.

Comment: Why would example 2 store only one file? Is it because fastcars.pdf and sportscars.pdf are identical? Or do the titles have to be unique, as well as the file names?

Comment: As this question is _not_ about the structure and meaning of data in _Portable Document Format_, please remove the `pdf`-tag. In addition, please make it explicit that this is about "pdf names", not about file contents. As this is tagged `java` and reads `Most suitable data structure`, think [Java Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections).

Comment: @JimMischel Yes the title's have to be unique too.  I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I took the console input ..

**testcase#1** 
 i/p:

```
  FastCars fastcars.pdf
  EvenFasterCars fastcars.pdf
  NotSoFastCars cars.pdf
  SlowCars slowcars.pdf
```

o/p:

```
slowcars.pdf
 fastcars.pdf
 cars.pdf
```

**testcase#2**

i/p:

```
 FastCars fastcars.pdf
 EvenFasterCars fastcars.pdf
 FastCars sportscars.pdf
 EvenFasterCars sportscars.pdf
```

o/p:

```
  sportscars.pdf
```

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
        Map<String,String> map1=new HashMap<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> map2=new HashMap<String,String>();


        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            String inpt[]=br.readLine().split(" ");
            String tag=inpt[0];
            String fileName=inpt[1];
            map1.put(tag,fileName);
            map2.put(fileName, tag);
        }

        Set<String> keySet=map1.keySet();
        Iterator it=keySet.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String key=(String)it.next();
            if(map2.containsKey(map1.get(key)))
            {
                System.out.println(map1.get(key));
                map2.remove(map1.get(key));
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every conforming PDF file has a unique ID as part of it's metadata. You might want to just use that string as the file name. Most PDF library tools allow easy access to this metadata.